TripAdvisor is adding -mapper to my API key
I am trying a simple request to test the TripAdvisor API :
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest
                .newBuilder()
                .uri(URI
                        .create("https://api.content.tripadvisor.com/api/v1/location/search?key=" + TRIPADVISOR_API_KEY + "&searchQuery=" + QUERY
                                + "&language=fr"))
                .header("accept", "application/json")
                .method("GET", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody())
                .build();
        HttpResponse<String> response = HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        System.out.println(response.body());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

and TripAdvisor returns me the following response :
{
  "error": {
    "message": "invalid client key: <TRIPADVISOR_API_KEY>-mapper",
    "type": "UnauthorizedException",
    "code": "160"
  }
}

<TRIPADVISOR_API_KEY> is obviously the provided key.
I do not understand what is this '-mapper' suffix added to the key.
Do anybody have encounter the same problem or can give me some clues about what happens?
I tries a similar code with Jsoup or HttpUrlConnection, i have the same problem every time.

Have you double checked that TRIPADVISOR_API_KEY does not contain -mapper part?

@Justinas yes, it is the correct key, without the '-mapper' string

Does your key and query are URL encoded? Maybe it's actually unauthorized, and -mapper is irrelevant?

@Justinas. Thanks for your suggestions :) I try with the key and query URL encoded and not encoded, i have the same response each time.

It seems you're not the only one; here's another person with the same problem: https://x.com/levelsio/status/1812225730308427969

@k314159 Thanks for the link. I activated my key today, maybe its due to a needed activation time. I waited the 15 minutes they asked for, i even made tries for 2 hours before posting here. I will see if the problem solve by itself.

After one day, the problem disappears. The error message was misleading, and the documentation was unclear, as they say to wait for 15 minutes after the creation.
